# cron not running program

Tags: linux, cron

I tried to add a command to cron, but it won't run. I'm using crontab -e to edit, and after extensive googling, I can't find the solution to my problem.

this is my crontab:

```
    SHELL=/bin/sh
    PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
    * * * * * /usr/bin/notify-send hello
```

I already checked if cron is running with ps -A|grep 'cron'.
It is running. I am on an arch system with systemd and cronie.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to tell whether its "working" or not is to look in cron daemon log file e.g. `/var/log/crond.log`.
The `'* * * * *'` part in your cron table would mean to run your job every minute. Is this really what you want?